# Can Observable.Timer() lead to memory leaks?

Tags: .net, timer, system.reactive, observable

Recently I noticed a small bug in my code which uses Reactive Extensions. I was subscribing to Timer but I never disposed my subscription. This resulted in a memory leak.

I created snippet which highlights this danger:

```
while (true)
{
    Observable.Timer(TimeSpan.Zero, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1)).Subscribe(Console.WriteLine);
}
```

Is this normal behaviour?

Shouldn't scheduler hold weak reference to timer to get it garbage collected when subscribers lost connection with the rest of the app?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is normal, and is a *feature*.

The semantics for Subscribe() are listen forever, or until Disposed() or OnCompleted(), or OnError(), which ever comes first.

Answer (score 7):

You *can* keep a reference to the subscription, and even combine them with a `CompositeDisposable`, but the usual method of managing `IObservable` lifetime on an otherwise infinite operator (like `Timer`) is by using an operator that applies termination rules to another, like `Take` (take x values), `TakeWhile` (take values while `f(x)` returns true) or `TakeUntil` (take values until another sequence, *y*, emits a value or completes).

Running Rx operators won't be automatically GC'd unless they've completed. `Timer` / `Interval`, for example, both recursively schedule their next value using an `IScheduler` and the default instances of the various schedulers are all accessible via static properties of `Scheduler`. This makes the running operator always rooted and therefore unavailable for GC.

Answer (score 1):

I don't agree with the answer.
What you're essentially doing is redundant as you're using an infinite loop to create successive observables, hence the memory leak.
Remove the while loop and just have one Observable.Timer or even better use an Observable.Interval. Just one instance then when you don't need it anymore call dispose on it.

Comment: The code was a simplified example code to make the problem more obvious. I think the author is aware of what you wrote.