# Should disposable items in collection be disposed before collection is reinstainated?

Tags: c#, .net, system.reactive, disposable

I have class

```
class A {
    IObservable<long> poll = new Observable.Interval(100 ms).Do((ms) => LoadData());

    void Subscribe() {
        poll.Subscribe();
    }
}
```

I have class

```
class B {
    IEnumerable<A> Items { get; }

    void Refresh() {
        Items = GetNewListWithNewJustCreatedInstances();
    }
}
```

User subscribes to many items multiple times, then he calls Refresh() to reload items from some server (obviously, he subscribes to new items again). Will all old subscriptions automagically dispose or I should implement something like this?

```
class A : IDisposable {
    void Dispose() {
        poll.Dispose();
    }
}

class B {
    void Refresh() {
        foreach (var item in Items) {
            item.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If you don't have a specific problem you're trying to fix here, just let the garbage collector do its job.

Comment: @EdPlunkett I'm not trying to fix a problem, I'm just worried that my timer will continue to execute each 100 msecs after I hit Refresh() method and that each time I hit Refresh() number of those subscriptions will rise. Because I am **not** disposing **items**, I just recreate and repopulate collection with **new** items (if user has reference to old item in some variable, I suppose it will stay alive).

Comment: That should be easy to test. If it keeps firing... yeah, you'll need to swat 'em.

Comment: Yeah, I figured. Unfortunately don't have the environment to test it now, just the code :) Will test it tomorrow.

Comment: @EdPlunkett - Are you expecting the garbage collector to dispose of the subscriptions?

Comment: @Enigmativity Uhhh... Maybe I was.

Comment: @EdPlunkett - The GC never calls dispose. The GC **may** call a destructor which calls dispose, but you can't guarantee that it will. You have to explicitly check if the object has a destructor which calls dispose.

Comment: @EwanCoder - Can you please let us know what this design is trying to solve? It can probably be done a whole lot cleaner, but I can't say how unless you can let us know what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: @Enigmativity I have list with items loaded from some server. Each item has IObservable for changed data. Observable.Interval starts when the first subscription is made and it disposes when the last subscription is unsubscribed. So server is not queried for changed data until anyone subscribes, and server **do** start to **poll** data each 100 msecs once there's at least one subscription. But number of items can eventually change, and when user calls Refresh to reload whole set of items from the server (they are being recreated), old items are possibly still polling...

Comment: @EwanCoder - Yes, that's what you're doing, but what is the problem you're solving?

Comment: @Enigmativity The problem is the question really whether should I call Dispose() method in foreach cycle on each item containing this Observable.interval before executing Refresh() method which reinitializes everything.

Comment: @EwanCoder - Sorry, I don't think I'm explaining myself very well. I'm not asking about the problem that you have with this particular solution, but instead what is the problem that this solution is trying to solve. I want to understand if there is a better architecture to solve your underlying business need.

Comment: @Enigmativity I have a server with hierarchical list of nodes. Each node has some data properties. Each node can change over time and I need to be able to subscribe for those changes as well as get any node values in any given time. At start, I read all structure and construct hierarchical data class which contains all nodes and it's initial read values, so the user can access them as _client.Nodes[someId]. But then number of nodes at server side can change, so I need to call Refresh method which re-reads all nodes.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120683/discussion-between-enigmativity-and-ewancoder).

Answer (score 0):

Your code is a recipe for multiple memory leaks. See [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6246243/can-observable-timer-lead-to-memory-leaks).

Rx subscriptions stay alive forever until disposed, OnComplete called, or OnError. Garbage Collection won't clean them up. Since you're not disposing, and `Observable.Interval` never completes, each subscription will leak until you run out of memory. Your code leaves open the possibility of multiple subscriptions per instance of `A`, and obviously multiple `A` objects.

Here's some Linqpad-friendly code to test it out:

```
void Main()
{
    var a0 = new A();
    a0.Subscribe();
    a0.Subscribe();
    a0.Subscribe();
    a0.Dispose();
    a0 = null;

    GC.Collect(); //Has no effect. Demonstrates Garbage collection doesn't help.
}

class A : IDisposable
{
    IObservable<long> poll = Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(100)).Do(l => l.Dump());
    IDisposable disposable;
    public void Subscribe()
    {
        Dispose();
        //memory leak!!
        poll.Subscribe();

        //Use this instead
            //disposable = poll.Subscribe();
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        disposable?.Dispose();
    }
}
```

When the memory-leaking line is uncommented, and the safe one commented, you'll see three numbers pop out per interval, one for each subscription. When the disposable-tracking line is uncommented, and the memory leak commented out, you should see no output.

Comment: Will garbage collector automatically dispose class A if I had reinitialized IEnumerable<A> with new set of instances of the class A, but did not call all old instances a.Dispose()?

Comment: The problem isn't instances of class `A`. The problem is instances of the subscription. Imagine `poll.Subscribe` returning an object that doesn't get collected as garbage, because there's some mystery internal class holding a strong reference to it that only gets chucked on `Dispose`. So your scenario may have garbage collection clean up the `A` instance, but not the subscription instance(s).

Comment: @EwanCoder - The GC **never** calls `.Dispose()`. The only (sort-of) exception to this is if there is a finalizer that you know explicitly calls `.Dispose()` then this **may** get called by the GC. Rx subscriptions **do not** have a finalizer so the GC will not dispose of them for you.